# JQuery Custom Scrollbar Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to use the Jquery Scrollbar plugin from the below link..
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

I'm working on a web application chat window UI, I wanted to use a dark-thick jquery scrollbar for the Chat message body. The chat window will be opened upon click of a button after 8 seconds. Below are my questions...

I'm able to add this custom scrollbar using Chrome develepor tools console but not directly as the window is loading on the fly..

1. Where do I need to write the code "$("#id").mCustomScrollbar()" as the chat window is loaded upon the click of a button;
2. Also, in the message body div element the scrollbar plugin is creating another div with classes "mCustomScrollBox mCS-dark-thick". Whenever a message is sent, we are creating another div element to show in the message body. But this div is loading below the "plugin div", which is not correct as the messages are shown from bottom;

Comment: Can you add a jsbin or jsfiddle to your question with your problem?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/g46LM/3/

Comment: Here is the new jsfiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/g46LM/4/ ............. I'm able to figure out where to write the code of the scroll bar plugin.... I have taken an example in the fiddle of my current problem .... whenever I enter text inside the textbox, the div will be populated with it... while I'm keep on entering the text inside input box, at some point the div will have the scrollbar and the custom scrollbar plugin code is coming after the second time the key is pressed...  I want the custom scrollbar to be loaded as soon as the div has the scrollbar....

Comment: I don't know how to add external resource.. could you please tell me so that i can add it and show you the custom scrollbar plugin.. here is the link to download the custom scrollbar plugin......  https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin

Comment: here is the jsbin link ..... http://jsbin.com/UhoKogA/2/watch?html,css,js,output